# wxPython Reload a grid in a panel

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

I've got several classes so I prefer not to paste any code here (if that's possible :P)

The problem:
I've created a class which creates a frame, and this frame contains a panel.
In another class I've stored all my settings.

On the panel are several sizers and among other attributes, it has a grid.
This grid is build from sequence 1 on the x axis and sequence y on the y axis.

To create my panel, I've divided my code into sections (like buildLeft() buildRight() buildTopRight() and so on which are linked to a main sizer in the buildFrame() method).

My grid is created in the buildTopRight() section of this class. It creates the grid by retrieving the values for sequence1 and sequence2 from the settings object and creates a grid of the length of this sequence accordingly. After this is done, the grid is bound to the sizer for the topRight section.

I also have a dropdown list (wx.Choice). If i select another option from this list, I want to remove an item from my sequence 1 and sequence 2.
The code to do this already works, and the data in my settings object changes accordingly.

However, I'm not able to reload the matrix, since if i call the buildTopRight() method again, the matrix is recreated and cropped to the topleft side of my screen, while leaving the old matrix in place.

Please help.

On request, this is the code for building my panel:

```
# import modules
import wx
import wx.grid
import matrixSettings as ms

# Panel class
class ResultatenPanel(wx.Panel):
def __init__(self, parent, id):
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, id, style=wx.BORDER_SUNKEN)

    # link settings object
    self.matSet = self.GetGrandParent().ms

    # build the main sizers
    self.sizerMain = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    self.sizerMenu = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    self.sizerRight = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    self.sizerTopRight = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    self.sizerBotRight = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

    # make individual parts
    self.buildMenu()
    self.buildTopRight()
    self.buildBotRight()
    self.buildRight()

    # build total frame
    self.buildFrame()
```

build right code (includes top and bottom right bits):

```
def buildRight(self):
    self.sizerRight.Add(self.sizerTopRight, 5)
    self.sizerRight.Add(self.sizerBotRight, 2)
```

the code to build the frame:

```
def buildFrame(self):
    self.sizerMain.Add(self.sizerMenu, 1)
    self.sizerMain.Add(self.sizerRight, 5, wx.EXPAND)
    self.SetSizer(self.sizerMain)
```

top right code:

```
def buildTopRight(self):
    self.grid = wx.grid.Grid(self)

    print "buildTopRight called"
    if self.matSet.getAlgoritme() == "Needleman-Wunsch":
        self.matSet.setSeq1("-" + self.matSet.getSeq1())
        self.matSet.setSeq2("-" + self.matSet.getSeq2())

    # set grid
    self.grid.CreateGrid(len(self.matSet.getSeq2()), len(self.matSet.getSeq1()))
    self.grid.SetRowLabelSize(25)
    self.grid.DisableDragColSize()
    self.grid.DisableDragRowSize()

    # set the grid proportions accurately
    for x in range(0, len(self.matSet.getSeq1())):
        # set the grid proportions accurately
        for y in range(0, len(self.matSet.getSeq2())):
            self.grid.SetRowSize(y, 25)
            self.grid.SetRowLabelValue(y, self.matSet.getSeq2()[y].upper())

            self.grid.SetCellValue(y, x, "0")
            self.grid.SetReadOnly(y, x, True)

        self.grid.SetColSize(x, 25)
        self.grid.SetColLabelValue(x, self.matSet.getSeq1()[x].upper())
```

newly added:

```
    self.sizerTopRight.Clear()    
    self.sizerTopRight.Add(self.grid, 1)

    self.Update()
    self.Layout()
```

Comment: There's no way to diagnose your issue here without seeing the function bodies for your build* methods at the very minimum.

Comment: Where do you add something in self.sizerTopRight?

Comment: sorry, appearantly i forgot to add some code from the buildTopRight method. Using this code, the grid does seem to work (in a way). The grid is updated, but if a new - smaller grid is created, the old grid isn't removed. Its simply drawn over the old one, which means that if you remove an item from the grid and use the refresh button, the new (smaller) grid is placed over the old one, leavind 1 "old" row and column in place. I'm still trying to remove this column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is a not very memory friendly solution.
You should hide the current grid and create a new one:

```
self.sizerTopRight.Hide(self.grid)
self.sizerTopRight.Add(self.new_grid, 1)
self.sizerTopRight.Show(self.new_grid)
self.Layout()
```

Comment: So how would be the best way to create the grid and new_grid in this way? I already have a grid object and keep recreating one in the buildTopRight method by this code: "self.grid = wx.grid.Grid(self)"

Comment: I've added         

        try:
            self.sizerTopRight.Hide(self.grid)
        except:
            print "no grid build yet"
to the program. and added the .Add and .Show methods like you suggested. It works perfectly now, thanks!